# insert a list to a binary tree

Tags: python, insert, binary-tree

I have a list like this :

```
a=[(("x",0.312),("e",0.0232),("f",0.245),("a",0.1322))]
```

and now i want to insert it to a Max Heap Tree and each node has to have both value eg:("x",0.312) and i can get both value separately. I know how to implement the Max Heap. I need help with how to deal with the insert function. 
It can be a binary tree if its easier. Thanks

```
class Heap:
def __init__(self):
    self.heap = list()

#return the size of the tree
def size(self):
    return len(self.heap)

def isLeaf(self, index):
    #returns true if the index refers to a leaf, false otherwise
    return self.size() < 2 * index + 2

def parent(self, index):
    #returns the parent of the node at index
    return(index - 1) // 2

def leftChild(self, index):
    #returns the index of the left child of a node
    return 2 * index + 1

def rightChild(self, index):
    #returns the index of the right child of a node
    return 2 * index + 2

def add(self, value):
    #add a given value to the heap
    #append the value to the list
    #shift the element into the correct position
    self.heap.append(value)
    index= self.size()-1
    while self.parent(index) >=0 and self.heap[index] < self.heap[self.parent(index)]:
        swap= self.heap[index]
        self.heap[index]=self.heap[self.parent(index)]
        self.heap[self.parent(index)]=swap
        index = self.parent(index)
```

Comment: Have you looked at the [heapq](http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html) module?

Comment: @TommyNgo is this an exercise or will you accept answers suggesting modules already created for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest creating an object for each tuple and using a list of those objects with the [`heapq`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html) module. That way you can control the sort order and turn a min heap into a max heap. You can also access the former tuple elements independently as attributes:

```
import heapq

class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, letter, value):
        self.letter = letter
        self.value = value

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Item({0}, {1})".format(self.letter, self.value)

    def __le__(self, other):
        # This is where you control whether it's a min heap or a max heap,
        # and also what you want to sort on: value, letter or both.
        return self.value > other.value

items = [Item(*x) for x in a]
heapq.heapify(items)
```

**EDIT:** Changed `<` to `>`.

Comment: sorry, anyway I was just wondering if OP actually wants to implement this himself or not